# C++: passing a function to a constructor when using Eigen

Tags: c++, class, constructor, eigen

I'm using Eigen in a class that I'm working on. Here's the code excerpt:

```
class model {

public:
    Eigen::MatrixXd Ac;

    model (vars &, std::function<Eigen::MatrixXd()>, std::function<Eigen::MatrixXd()>);
};

model::model (vars & vars, std::function<Eigen::MatrixXd()> muX, 
std::function<Eigen::MatrixXd()> muX2)

    //update Ac
    Ac = muX(vars) + muX2(vars);


};
```

The idea is that when creating an object of `model`, the user will have to supply the functions `muX` and `muX2`, and the class will fill in values in `MatrixXd Ac` using `muX` and `muX2`. `vars` is just a class consisting of multiple variables that I created, and `muX` and `muX2` are expected to use the data in `vars` as input.

However, in my XCode, it's giving me an error saying: "No matching function for call to object of type `std::function". I haven't compiled yet but I think the compiler will give me the same error.

Comment: `vars & vars`?? That's terrible naming. I am sure you can come up with something more meaningful -- either the type, the variable, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::function<Eigen::MatrixXd()>` implies that it takes a function which accepts no arguments and returns an `Eigen::MatrixXd`, which I think is not what you want to do. You probably want to change it to `std::function<Eigen::MatrixXd(vars&)>`

Comment: In fact, I want to take in a `vars` and return a `MatrixXd`. Also, why do I need `const`?